# Getting 504 server error when trying to access localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: java, spring, prerender, http-status-code-504

Actually, I am trying to use prerender[DOT]io and have added prerender filter in to my server side application (in Java Spring).

I wrote a filter for prerender (middleware is service[DOT]prerender[DOT]io/)

```
private void initPrerenderFilter(ServletContext servletContext, EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
    log.debug("Registering prerender Filter");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic prerenderFilter = servletContext.addFilter("prerender", new PreRenderSEOFilter());

            prerenderFilter.setInitParameter("prerenderToken", MyToken);

    prerenderFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/*");
    prerenderFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
}
```

and have added dependency in pom.xml. localhost:8080 is working.

When I access `http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=`     I am getting the following error:

> The server for `http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=` took too
>   long to respond. It may be overloaded.

Comment: It worked on production server.

Comment: You might be sending "localhost:8080" to our hosted service, where we wouldn't be able to access your localhost. Send me an email at todd@prerender.io with more info and I'll be happy to look into it.